# Can't properly serve static files in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to serve a static image to a css file using flask. I am using `render_template()` to to get the html file, and I have a static directory for my css and javascript. My other image is loading, but the image that I am referencing from the css file is not working and I get his from the flask terminal: `GET /static/static/res/typewriter.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404`

I tried typing in the path in my browser and it works fine

This is how I am referencing the image since the CSS file is already in the static directory. `background-image: url("/res/typewriter.jpg");`

I hope there is an easy fix for this, especially since I am new to this stuff. Thanks!

Comment: What path are you typing in the browser?

Comment: I typed in ```[my_local_ip]:[port]/static/res/image.jpg```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html file you should have this in the header:

```
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='mainpage.css') }}">
```

... as long as your static directory is named static. In several of my Flask applications I am importing Bootstrap css like so:

```
  <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.css') }}">
```

Ensure you are visiting http://127.0.0.1:5000 in your browser (unless you changed the default).

Also here is a random example of how I serve images from the static directory:

```
h1 class="display-3"> <img src="/static/title_welcome.png" alt="about"></h1>
```

Comment: Sure no problem. Wasn't sure if your path was right... noticed you have a static/ dir inside a static/ dir.  Good luck